# Views with the same width and height

Tags: android, layout, view, constraints

Is there a simple way to create xml layout like this below in android studio? I'm the iOS XCode guy and its no problem to do this there using ratio constraints.

So far I'm using `ConstraintLayout` and vertical `gridlines` with percent option. But this only gives me equal widths view1 and view2 and no height.

I know about overriding `onMeasure` method solution, but I want to avoid it.

```
              a
---------------------------
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|      b           b      |
| ----------- ----------- | 
| |   view1 | |   view2 | |
| |b        | |b        | |
| |         | |         | |
| ----------- ----------- |
---------------------------

b = 50% * a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, in your activity or fragment, you get 2 views with `findViewById();`

And then:

```
    ImageView view_instance1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
ImageView view_instance2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view_instance1 .getLayoutParams();
        params.height= params.width;
        view_instance1 .setLayoutParams(params);
        view_instance2 .setLayoutParams(params);
```